# Slips System of BCC

Tags: crystal-structure, crystallography

We have been taught that there are 48 slip Systems in BCC. I need the miller indices of each slip plane and direction.

Out of 48 I got miller indices of 12 systems of $\{110\}\ \left<111\right>$ and 12 systems of $\{112\}\ \left<111\right>$ , but I am not getting remaining 24 slip Systems of $\{123\}\ \left<111\right>$.

I don't know how to find all 24 planes of $\{123\}$ family of planes.If anyone know how to do it, it will be helpful

Comment: This is simple enumeration of the possibilities. There are more because there are no repeats of indices that are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

> How to find all 24 planes of $\{123\}$ family of planes?

For any of the $\left<111\right>$ directions, we have $3!$ i.e. $6$ $\{123\}$ slip planes. And we have $4$ $\left<111\right>$ slip directions for each plane. So in total $6\times 4 = 24$ slip systems.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE!  Notice the markup improvements with MathJax. If you havn't already, consider taking a minute to look over the [help center](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help) and [tour page](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) to better understand our guidelines and question policies.